# How to write a SQL Query that returns all names of players who ...?

Tags: mysql, relational-division

I want to write a SQL Query that returns all the names of `Players` who `PlaysMatches` with everyone they know.

There are 3 tables:

- Players (ID, name)
- Knows (ID, Player1_ID, Player2_ID)
- PlaysMatches (ID, Player1_ID, Player2_ID)

Where table `Knows` implies that `Player1` knows `Player2`, and table `PlaysMatches` implies that `Player1` plays match with `Player2`.

My problem with my query is that it returns names of players that plays a match with at least one player they know, not everyone they know.

What shall I change in my query to let it display the everyone they know part?

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT P1.name
    FROM Players P1, Players P2
    WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM  PlaysMatches PL
                WHERE P1.id = PL.Player1_id AND P2.id = PL.Player2_id)
                AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM Knows K
                            WHERE P1.id = K.Player1_id AND P2.id = K.Player2_id))
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achive what I understand you want by kind of reversing the logic of your current query. I.e. ask for players where no record in `knows` exists for which no match exists.

```
SELECT p.name
       FROM players p
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM knows k
                                WHERE p.id IN (k.player1_id,
                                               k.player2_id)
                                      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                             FROM playsmatches pm
                                                             WHERE pm.player1_id = k.player1_id
                                                                   AND pm.player2_id = k.player2_id
                                                                    OR pm.player1_id = k.player2_id
                                                                       AND pm.player2_id = k.player1_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be translated to: Find all players who can say "I know no player who I didn't play against". This is very similar to Joe Celko's "There ain’t no planes in this hangar that I can’t fly!" from [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). There are multiple ways to answer the question with SQL. In your case I would use the following:

```
select p.name
from Players p
left join Knows k on k.Player1_ID = p.ID
left join PlaysMatches m
  on  m.Player1_ID = k.Player1_ID
  and m.Player2_ID = k.Player2_ID
group by p.name
having sum(k.Player2_ID is not null and m.Player2_ID is null) = 0
```

All players are (left) joined with players they know. The second (left) join will find the corresponding matches. If no match is found, the condition `k.Player2_ID is not null and m.Player2_ID is null` will be TRUE. Read it as "I know Player2 (`k.Player2_ID is not null`) but I never played against him/her (`m.Player2_ID is null`)". If this condition is TRUE for any Player2 from `Knows` table, the `SUM(..)` will be `> 0`.

**Note:**

```
sum(k.Player2_ID is not null and m.Player2_ID is null) = 0
```

works in MySQL because a bolean expression returns `0` or `1` (or `NULL`, but not in this case). If you want it to be standard compliant, use:

```
sum(case when k.Player2_ID is not null and m.Player2_ID is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

**Note 2:** The query will also return all players who know no one. If you don't want that, change the frist LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN. You can also change the HAVING clause to

```
having sum(m.Player2_ID is null) = 0
```

since `k.Player2_ID is not null` is always true for an INNER JOIN.

**Note 3:** Another HAVING condition could also be:

```
having count(distinct k.Player2_ID) = count(distinct m.Player2_ID)
```

**Note 4:** For a better performance I would use `group by p.ID` instead of `group by p.name`. This should work on most MySQL configurations. But might fail on MariaDB with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enabled.